# Conexão postgreSQL com Django

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework

Boa tarde, estou tendo um problema na conexão do Django com o PostgreSQL

Instalei o psycopg2 no django, mudei a conexão no settings.py para conectar com o postgre e quando dou o runserver ele roda me retornando o ip mas na pagina da "Page not found (404)"

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME','apiWikkiDjango'),
'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER','postgres'),
'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS','root'),
'HOST': 'localhost',
'PORT': '5432',
}
}
```

Clicando no IP fornecido da esse erro, mas fazendo os testes como get, post, etc no postman, tudo funciona normal.

Minha url principal:

Minha url principal está assim:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^produto$', ProdutoList.as_view()),
    url(r'^produto/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', ProdutoDetalhes.as_view()),

    url(r'^pedido$', PedidoList.as_view()),
    url(r'^pedido/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', PedidoDetalhes.as_view()),

    url(r'^usuario$', UsuarioList.as_view()),
]
```

A outra url está assim:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls'))
]
```

[image: Essa é a pagina que vejo ao clicar no ip]

Comment: Você tem alguma página mapeada no urls.py do projeto? Tem um Swagger instalado que queira mostrar as urls no browser?

Comment: De acordo a mensagem você acessou a URL sem informar o path, e seu url.py está mapeado apenas para `admin/` e `^api/`